# In intellij, it prints the classpath which is nice but I only see class directories on the class path?

Tags: intellij-idea

I see this in my classpath in intellij

```
authservice/out/production/classes:
```

however, I don't see this which exists and contains logback.xml

```
authservice/out/production/resources
```

I ask as this statement is returning null and logback is not loading

```
URL resource = ServerUtil.class.getResource("/logback.xml");
```

Worse yet is this is intermittent as every once a week or month, this occurs BUT whether it works or not, I don't see authservice/out/production/resources in the classpath which is weird.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [the logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085). Enable debug logging for `build.log`. You can [report the bug directly](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) or [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new).

Comment: @CrazyCoder it's intermittent so it goes away.  is there a capture button to capture bugs like chrome has that I just click and it gathers the info and sends it in?     (perhaps I can catch it that way).  Hard to create minimal and complete when it's intermittent and goes away somehow.

Comment: Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data, but debug logging for build.log needs to be enabled beforehand per the document linked in the first comment.

Comment: Have you tried with Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("logback.xml");